# Location in background and simulator

Tags: ios, sdk, background, ios-simulator, core-location

I need to make the application which use exact coordinates every 1 secound.
**I know about battery drain - this app will work only on power** (wires in car).
But I need to use not significand, but high accuracy coordinates very often (and in background, because use navigation program at this time).

I try a lot of examples from some articles about corelocation in background.
I make delegate of CLLocationManagerDelegate
Make function locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
**Write backgroungmode:location in .plist** 
in my log I see coordinates.
But when I click on home button - everithing stops.
I get coordinates in background mode one time in 5min.
Is it a problem with app or feature of simulator?

I compile and start some examples from github etc - everything the same

I don't have yet iPhone - because to buy or not to buy depends of "can I write this app".
In android it's really easy - I make location listener and Service - and get coordinates every secound.

Update:
I use this example:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/

```
2013-01-05 11:26:41.162 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.331504 Longitude: -122.030716
2013-01-05 11:26:42.166 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.331464 Longitude: -122.030721
2013-01-05 11:26:43.148 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.331426 Longitude: -122.030728
2013-01-05 11:26:44.161 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.331388 Longitude: -122.030728
2013-01-05 11:26:45.172 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.331351 Longitude: -122.030735
```

Press Home button

```
2013-01-05 11:30:35.147 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.330071 Longitude: -122.021223
2013-01-05 11:35:35.176 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.324633 Longitude: -122.024034
2013-01-05 11:40:36.153 BackgroundLocationTrackingExample[3402:f803]  Latitude: 37.330647 Longitude: -122.030024
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow Background Location Updating:

• Go to Info.plist

• Add an new Row

• Call the row "UIBackgroundModes"

• In that row call "Location Updating"

Your done but keep in Mind Background Location KILLS battery Life :)

Comment: Also you need to add this in your project description, that application will drain your device battery

Comment: That's true that you must mention in the description that your app runs in the background (App will be rejected if you didn't).

Comment: Make sure in the code you don't have [locationmanger startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; This code doesn't allow precise location updating in iOS. And how are you detecting battery changed because the simulater can't detect battery plugged in or not (Only a real Device).